# Generate C# Class with svcutil.exe against xsd using External tools in VS 2012

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe, xsd.exe, xsd2code, external-tools

I have created a C# Data Contract class against XSD and used my WCF service. And I have setup the xsd.exe using Visual Studio External Tools like below,

Use bat file with:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"

xsd %1 %2 /classes /language:CS
```

and then used bat file in external tools.

```
Title : XSD
Command :C:\Tools\bin\xsd.bat
Arguments : "$(ItemPath)" "/outputdir:$(ProjectDir)"
```

to this setup I am getting a class file in my project directory.

So, My question is how to set up same kind of external tools  in visual studio for SVCUTIL.EXE tool.

please suggest the better ways of doing..

I am having a XSD file and I need pure Data Contract c sharp class for this.

I have tried SVCutil.exe tool in command line option.

```
svcutil.exe "E:\Test.xsd" /dconly
```

Getting this error:
Error: Type 'LoadReference' in namespace '' cannot be imported. Complex types with simple content extension are not supported. Either change the schema so that
the types can map to data contract types or use ImportXmlType or use a different serializer.

It seems like this tool not supporting complex types.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What have you tried?  [ServiceModel Metadata Utility Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I have tried to generate C# class file using svcutil.exe

Comment: And the result was...?  Nothing?  The wrong class?  An error?

Comment: Tim - I have updated the error in this post itself.

Comment: Take a look at step 5 in the following article:  http://blog.shutupandcode.net/?p=761